# What is the difference between cross_validate and cross_val_score?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I understand `cross_validate` and how it works, but now I am confused about what  `cross_val_score` actually does. Can anyone give me some example?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`cross_val_score` is a helper function on the estimator and the dataset.

Would explain it with an example:

```
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
>>> clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
>>> scores = cross_val_score(clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=5)
>>> scores                                              
array([ 0.96...,  1.  ...,  0.96...,  0.96...,  1.        ])
```

This example demonstrates how to estimate the accuracy of a linear kernel support vector machine on the iris dataset by splitting the data, fitting a model and computing the score 5 consecutive times (with different splits each time)

The `cross_validate` function differs from `cross_val_score` in two ways -

1. It allows specifying multiple metrics for evaluation.
2. It returns a dict containing training scores, fit-times and score-times in
   addition to the test score.

Note: When the cv argument is an integer, `cross_val_score` uses the **KFold** or **StratifiedKFold** strategies by default, the latter being used if the estimator derives from ClassifierMixin

You can go through this [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) for better understanding

Different [examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/75177/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score) using `cross_val_score`, you can go through about its different implementations.

Answer (score 2):

1. `cross_val_score`: calculate score for each CV split
2. `cross_validate`: calculate one or more scores and timings for each CV split